# Join tables together

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I need to write a SQL statement to find the ‘Action’ (category) films with the shortest running time (length). Your query should output the titles and lengths of the films. This is the database schema I have.
[image]

```
CREATE TABLE category (
  category_id NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
  name varchar2(25)
);

CREATE TABLE film_category (
  film_id NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
  category_id NUMBER(3) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE film (
  film_id NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
  title varchar2(255),
  description varchar2(255),
  release_year NUMBER(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  language_id NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
  original_language_id NUMBER(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  rental_duration NUMBER(3) DEFAULT 3 NOT NULL,
  rental_rate NUMBER(4,2) DEFAULT '4.99' NOT NULL,
  length NUMBER(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  replacement_cost NUMBER(5,2) DEFAULT '19.99' NOT NULL,
  rating varchar2(8) DEFAULT 'G' NOT NULL,
  special_features varchar2(255) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

I created 3 tables and inserted some records on these tables.

I write my query like this:

```
 SELECT F.title, MIN(F.length)
 FROM FILM F JOIN
 FILM_CATEGORY FC
 ON F.FILM_ID = FC.FILM_ID RIGHT JOIN
 CATEGORY C
 ON C.CATEGORY_ID = FC.CATEGORY_ID 
 WHERE C.NAME = 'ACTION'
 GROUP BY title;
```

But there are no rows selected when I execute this query, any hints? Thanks in advance.

---

Update: Insert some records to tables

```
INSERT INTO category VALUES(1, 'Action');
INSERT INTO category VALUES(2, 'Animation');
INSERT INTO category VALUES(3, 'Children');
INSERT INTO category VALUES(4, 'Classics');
INSERT INTO category VALUES(5, 'Comedy');
INSERT INTO category VALUES(6, 'Documentary');
INSERT INTO category VALUES(7, 'Drama');
INSERT INTO category VALUES(8, 'Family');
INSERT INTO category VALUES(9, 'Foreign');
INSERT INTO category VALUES(10, 'Games');
INSERT INTO category VALUES(11, 'Horror');
INSERT INTO category VALUES(12, 'Music');
INSERT INTO category VALUES(13, 'New');
INSERT INTO category VALUES(14, 'Sci-Fi');
INSERT INTO category VALUES(15, 'Sports');
INSERT INTO category VALUES(16, 'Travel');

INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(19, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(21, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(29, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(38, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(56, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(67, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(97, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(105, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(111, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(115, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(126, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(130, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(162, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(194, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(205, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(210, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(212, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(229, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(250, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(252, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(253, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(271, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(287, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(292, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(303, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(318, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(327, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(329, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(360, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(371, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(375, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(395, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(417, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(501, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(511, 1);
INSERT INTO film_category VALUES(530, 1);

INSERT INTO film VALUES(19, 'AMADEUS HOLY', 'A Emotional Display of a Pioneer And a Technical Writer who must Battle a Man in A Baloon', 1959, 1, NULL, 6, '0.99', 113, '20.99', 'PG', 'Commentaries');
INSERT INTO film VALUES(20, 'AMELIE HELLFIGHTERS', 'A Boring Drama of a Woman And a Squirrel who must Conquer a Student in A Baloon', 1965, 1, NULL, 4, '4.99', 79, '23.99', 'R', 'Commentaries');
INSERT INTO film VALUES(21, 'AMERICAN CIRCUS', 'A Insightful Drama of a Girl And a Astronaut who must Face a Database Administrator in A Shark Tank', 1966, 1, NULL, 3, '4.99', 129, '17.99', 'R', 'Trailers');
INSERT INTO film VALUES(22, 'AMISTAD MIDSUMMER', 'A Emotional Character Study of a Dentist And a Crocodile who must Meet a Sumo Wrestler in California', 1994, 1, NULL, 6, '2.99', 85, '10.99', 'G', 'Trailers');
INSERT INTO film VALUES(23, 'ANACONDA CONFESSIONS', 'A Lacklusture Display of a Dentist And a Dentist who must Fight a Girl in Australia', 1986, 1, NULL, 3, '0.99', 92, '9.99', 'R', 'Commentaries');
INSERT INTO film VALUES(24, 'ANALYZE HOOSIERS', 'A Thoughtful Display of a Explorer And a Pastry Chef who must Overcome a Feminist in The Sahara Desert', 2001, 1, NULL, 6, '2.99', 181, '19.99', 'R', 'Deleted Scenes');
INSERT INTO film VALUES(25, 'ANGELS LIFE', 'A Thoughtful Display of a Woman And a Astronaut who must Battle a Robot in Berlin', 1981, 1, NULL, 3, '2.99', 74, '15.99', 'G', 'Trailers');
INSERT INTO film VALUES(26, 'ANNIE IDENTITY', 'A Amazing Panorama of a Pastry Chef And a Boat who must Escape a Woman in An Abandoned Amusement Park', 1982, 1, NULL, 3, '0.99', 86, '15.99', 'G', 'Behind the Scenes');
INSERT INTO film VALUES(27, 'ANONYMOUS HUMAN', 'A Amazing Reflection of a Database Administrator And a Astronaut who must Outrace a Database Administrator in A Shark Tank', 1995, 1, NULL, 7, '0.99', 179, '12.99', 'NC-17', 'Commentaries');
INSERT INTO film VALUES(28, 'ANTHEM LUKE', 'A Touching Panorama of a Waitress And a Woman who must Outrace a Dog in An Abandoned Amusement Park', 1968, 1, NULL, 5, '4.99', 91, '16.99', 'PG-13', 'Commentaries');
INSERT INTO film VALUES(29, 'ANTITRUST TOMATOES', 'A Fateful Yarn of a Womanizer And a Feminist who must Succumb a Database Administrator in Ancient India', 1987, 1, NULL, 5, '2.99', 168, '11.99', 'NC-17', 'Deleted Scenes');
INSERT INTO film VALUES(30, 'ANYTHING SAVANNAH', 'A Epic Story of a Pastry Chef And a Woman who must Chase a Feminist in An Abandoned Fun House', 1980, 1, NULL, 4, '2.99', 82, '27.99', 'R', 'Trailers');
INSERT INTO film VALUES(31, 'APACHE DIVINE', 'A Awe-Inspiring Reflection of a Pastry Chef And a Teacher who must Overcome a Sumo Wrestler in A U-Boat', 1964, 1, NULL, 5, '4.99', 92, '16.99', 'NC-17', 'Commentaries');
INSERT INTO film VALUES(32, 'APOCALYPSE FLAMINGOS', 'A Astounding Story of a Dog And a Squirrel who must Defeat a Woman in An Abandoned Amusement Park', 1995, 1, NULL, 6, '4.99', 119, '11.99', 'R', 'Trailers');
INSERT INTO film VALUES(33, 'APOLLO TEEN', 'A Action-Packed Reflection of a Crocodile And a Explorer who must Find a Sumo Wrestler in An Abandoned Mine Shaft', 1980, 1, NULL, 5, '2.99', 153, '15.99', 'PG-13', 'Deleted Scenes');
INSERT INTO film VALUES(34, 'ARABIA DOGMA', 'A Touching Epistle of a Madman And a Mad Cow who must Defeat a Student in Nigeria', 1971, 1, NULL, 6, '0.99', 62, '29.99', 'NC-17', 'Behind the Scenes');
INSERT INTO film VALUES(35, 'ARACHNOPHOBIA ROLLERCOASTER', 'A Action-Packed Reflection of a Pastry Chef And a Composer who must Discover a Mad Scientist in The First Manned Space Station', 2004, 1, NULL, 4, '2.99', 147, '24.99', 'PG-13', 'Trailers');
INSERT INTO film VALUES(36, 'ARGONAUTS TOWN', 'A Emotional Epistle of a Forensic Psychologist And a Butler who must Challenge a Waitress in An Abandoned Mine Shaft', 1996, 1, NULL, 7, '0.99', 127, '12.99', 'PG-13', 'Trailers');
INSERT INTO film VALUES(37, 'ARIZONA BANG', 'A Brilliant Panorama of a Mad Scientist And a Mad Cow who must Meet a Pioneer in A Monastery', 1960, 1, NULL, 3, '2.99', 121, '28.99', 'PG', 'Commentaries');
INSERT INTO film VALUES(38, 'ARK RIDGEMONT', 'A Beautiful Yarn of a Pioneer And a Monkey who must Pursue a Explorer in The Sahara Desert', 1988, 1, NULL, 6, '0.99', 68, '25.99', 'NC-17', 'Deleted Scenes');
INSERT INTO film VALUES(39, 'ARMAGEDDON LOST', 'A Fast-Paced Tale of a Boat And a Teacher who must Succumb a Composer in An Abandoned Mine Shaft', 1961, 1, NULL, 5, '0.99', 99, '10.99', 'G', 'Trailers');
INSERT INTO film VALUES(40, 'ARMY FLINTSTONES', 'A Boring Saga of a Database Administrator And a Womanizer who must Battle a Waitress in Nigeria', 1968, 1, NULL, 4, '0.99', 148, '22.99', 'R', 'Trailers');
```

My dataset is bit huge and I can only show some of the data.

This is the result I have when I run the formatted code below, it doesn't work:

[image]

```
COLUMN F.title FORMAT A20
COLUMN MIN(F.length) FORMAT 999

SELECT F.title, MIN(F.length)
FROM FILM F JOIN
FILM_CATEGORY FC
ON F.FILM_ID = FC.FILM_ID RIGHT JOIN
CATEGORY C
ON C.CATEGORY_ID = FC.CATEGORY_ID 
WHERE C.NAME = 'Action'
GROUP BY title;
```

Comment: Without the records you inserted we won't be able to help

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Whether or not it's your actual data, that is not minimal for asking here. PS Please act on the rest of the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using Oracle, since you are using VARCHAR2.
If no records are returned, I assume you have your database set with case sensitivity on, so 'Action' <> 'ACTION'.

Either change your query so the case is correct, or change the where clause to not be case sensitive, and you should have data returned.

I also hope there are some indexes on the tables which you haven't mentioned...

Comment: Yes, you're right! It's case sensitive. Do you know how to format the result? I can't do it with `COLUMN F.title FORMAT A20`

Comment: What format are you trying to achieve? Perhaps post the query you are using.
I haven't used sqlplus in years, I assume this is where you are trying to format it?

Comment: I've updated the question, please check

Comment: Perhaps you have values which are too long for the 20 characters, and need to wrap?
I can't see from the example, but you could try this:
COLUMN TITLE FORMAT A20 WRAP